# Date picker in mvc3 with razor view engine without using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to mvc3 and  i am using c# coding and razor my view engine. Is there any way to use date picker with out using jquery and something else.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't one build in. I think you have to roll your own

Comment: Are you trying to avoid JavaScript all together or just not use jQuery?

Comment: all scripting languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use javascript and jquery, well, you are left with HTML. And you know that in HTML you have standard input fields such as `<input type="text">`. Using pure HTML you cannot make a dynamic datepicker show when the user clicks on some date input.

Comment: And it sure is ugly to have an input, send the data to the server for model validation to parse the date and return the view again to tell the user the date format was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to avoid "all scripting languages" I suppose you should have three dropdowns,

1. Months (1 - 12)
2. Days (1 - 31)
3. Years

Your Model would need to take three seperate fields for Month, Day and Year. Then in your controller action you will need to do some Date parsing to make sure it is a valid date and if not, add a ModelState Exception.

Since MVC comes with jQuery (and the validators are very helpful), why are you trying to avoid using them?

All of it COULD be done with jQuery or even plain JavaScript so you're really limiting yourself.

**EDIT - Adding code sample**

Your Model

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class DatePickerViewModel
{
     [Required]
     [DisplayName("Month")]
     [Range(1,12,ErrorMessage = "Month must be between 1 and 12")]
     public int? Date_Month {get;set;}

     [Required]
     [DisplayName("Day")]
     [Range(1,31,ErrorMessage = "Day must be between 1 and 31")]
     public int? Date_Day {get;set;}

     [Required]
     [DisplayName("Day")]
     [Range(1900,2012,ErrorMessage = "Year must be between 1900 and 2012")]
     public int? Date_Year {get;set;}
}
```

Your controller

```
public class DatePickerController : Controller
{
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Choose()
     {
          return View(new DatePickerViewModel());
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Choose(DatePickerViewModel model)
     {
          if(!ModelState.IsValid)
               return View(model);
          else
          {
               DateTime date;
               if(!DateTime.TryParse(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",model.Date_Month, model.Date_Day, model.Date_Year),out dt))
               {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid Date");
                    return View(model);
               }

               //Do something with the variable "date"
               return View("SomeOtherView");
          }


     }
}
```

And your view

```
@model DatePickerViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
     <div>
          <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date_Month) @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.Date_Month)</div>
         <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Date_Month, (from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 12) select new SelectListItem{ Text = n==0? "":n.ToString(),Value =  n ==0? "":n.ToString()})</div>
     </div>
     <div>
          <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date_Day) @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.Date_Day)</div>
         <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Date_Day, (from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 31) select new SelectListItem{ Text = n==0? "":n.ToString(),Value =  n ==0? "":n.ToString()})</div>
     </div>
     <div>
          <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date_Year) @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.Date_Year)</div>
         <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Date_Year, (from n in Enumerable.Range(1899, 2012) select new SelectListItem{ Text = n==1899? "":n.ToString(),Value =  n == 1899? "":n.ToString()})</div>
     </div>
     <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
}
```

As you can see, the amound of raw code you need to create just to enable a date selector without using JavaScript at all is pretty large. Considering if you were to just use ANY jQuery date picker all you would need is a nullable DateTime property on your Model/ViewModel, a textbox on your view and a small snippet of JS to turn the text box in to a date selector.

Avoid re-inventing the wheel and reuse code that is already out there for how to use any jQuery Date Picker plugin.

Comment: when i am using jquery datepicker it's css is applying for my another controls like tree view.

Comment: What jQuery date picker are you using? Are you trying to use the one built in to jQuery UI? There are tons of different plugins, you're not stuck with using just what comes with jQuery UI. You could even use a hidden html input for "Date" and bind onchange events in jQuery to the month/year/day dropdowns to set the hidden inputs value. The point is giving us enough information to better assist you is key. Including what you've tried, what doesn't work, etc will help your questions get better responses. Maybe you should edit the question and ask for examples of date pickers?

Comment: thanks nick bork can you tell me step by step process for  should have three dropdowns,

Months (1 - 12)
Days (1 - 31)
Years
Your Model would need to take three seperate fields for Month, Day and Year. Then in your controller action you will need to do some Date parsing to make sure it is a valid date and if not, add a ModelState Exception.

Comment: I've added the code sample but I strongly suggest that you reconsider your approach. Re-inventing the wheel is far more complex than just fixing the reason why what ever date picker you're trying to use is causing issues with your TreeView.

Comment: ok nick bork my i know how to mismatch the jquery one from another because we are using lot of jqueries in our project.

Comment: may i now how get rid two java script plugins in mvc3

Comment: Depends on what plugin you're trying to remove, but thats completly off the topic of this question. In general, you would remove the script that loads the plugin from your page and any code that references the plugin.

Comment: when i tried chrome developer tool under console tab i have errors like some images are not found 404 error and one java script error how can i rectify that error

Comment: thanks nick bork it is working properly as you told me the tree view java script is showing error message under console panel how can i rectify the problem it is showing Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'treeview'.

Comment: Open another question for the tree view, post the code you're using.